# Download and unzip file with Python

Tags: python, download, zip

I am trying to download and open a zipped file and seem to be having trouble using a file type handle with zipfile. I'm getting the error "AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'" when running this:

```
import zipfile
import urllib2

def download(url,directory,name):
 webfile = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.sec.gov'+url)
 webfile2 = zipfile.ZipFile(webfile)
 content = zipfile.ZipFile.open(webfile2).read()
 localfile = open(directory+name, 'w')
 localfile.write(content)
 localfile.close()
 return()

download(link.get("href"),'./fails_data', link.text)
```

Answer (score 17):

Putting things together, the following retrieves the content of the first file within a zipped file from a website:

```py
import urllib.request
import zipfile
    
url = 'http://www.gutenberg.lib.md.us/4/8/8/2/48824/48824-8.zip'
filehandle, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
zip_file_object = zipfile.ZipFile(filehandle, 'r')
first_file = zip_file_object.namelist()[0]
file = zip_file_object.open(first_file)
content = file.read()
```

Comment: For newer python versions, do `import urllib.request as urllib` instead on the first line.

Comment: This doesn't keep it in memory, it'll write the zipped file to disk before unzipping it.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2020, you can use [dload](https://pypi.org/project/dload/) to download and unzip a file, i.e.:

```
import dload
dload.save_unzip("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/zip_2MB.zip")
```

By default it extracts to a dir on the script path with the zip file name, but you can specify the extract location:

```
dload.save_unzip("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/zip_2MB.zip", "/extract/here")
```

---

install using `pip install dload`

Comment: Is anyone maintaining this I haven't seen a single commit since march?

Comment: @Ari doesn't seem like it, which is unfortunate because it seems like a really cool package. I also run into [this error](https://github.com/x011/dload/issues/4) when using `save_unzip`

Comment: I also run into this error. ;(

Answer (score 5):

You can't seek on a `urllib2.urlopen`ed file. The methods it supports are listed here: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen.

You'll have to retrieve the file (possibly with `urllib.urlretrieve`, http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve), then use `zipfile` on it.

Alternatively, you could `read()` the `urlopen`ed file, then put it into a `StringIO`, then use `zipfile` on that, if you wanted the zipped data in memory. Also check out the `extract` and `extract_all` methods of `zipfile` if you just want to extract the file, instead of using `read`.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough rep to comment but regarding Marius's answer above please note that for Python3 there is a slight modification needed regarding import and urlretrieve call, since urllib has been split into several modules.

```
import urllib
```

Becomes:

```
import urllib.request
```

And

```
filehandle, _ = urllib.urlretrieve(url)
```

Becomes

```
filehandle, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterating on @Marius answer (which reads a single file directly from the zip), if you want to extract all files to a directory, do this:

```py
import urllib
import zipfile

url = "http://www.gutenberg.lib.md.us/4/8/8/2/48824/48824-8.zip"
extract_dir = "example"

zip_path, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path, "r") as f:
    f.extractall(extract_dir)
```

This stores the zip file in a temporary dir. If you want to keep it around, you can pass a filename to `urlretrieve`, e.g. `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "my_zip_file.zip")`.