# Using zipimport without a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

Is it possible to use `zipimport` in Python 2.x (2.6 and 2.7 are of interest) without having to "drop" the `.zip` file into a directory? If that's possible, how?

Basically, I want to hold the `.zip` in a buffer instead of putting it into a file.

Comment: You probably could create a ram disk and add a path to it to your Python search path.

Comment: Answer to ["Download and unzip file with Python"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6861390/2419207) describes method that you may want to use. Unluckily it doesn't have sample code attached.