# Downloading a Zip file and extracting its content in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, io, python-zipfile

I have this code to download a zip file from a URL and extract the contents.
But the name of the excel file changes every month. This would result in duplicates getting created. And it is not possible to predict the names each time new data gets published in the URL.

```
zip_file_url = "https://www.insee.fr/en/statistiques/series/xlsx/famille/102391902"  

import requests, zipfile, io  
r = requests.get(zip_file_url)  
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
    
z.extractall()
```

In the end I need to load the spreadsheet in Pandas. Can it be done without knowing the name of the spreadsheet within the zip file?

Is it possible to rename the Spreadsheet every time so that the file is overwritten and no duplicates are created? Also, how to load the spreadsheet in pandas without knowing the file name in future?

So, the best way would be to extract the file and save under same file name and overwrite the previous version. This means we also know the name of the spreadsheet to be loaded in pandas.

Comment: We need more information:
Is there only 1 excel file in the zip?
Is there only 1 excel file in the folder in which you want to extract?
What is the extension of your excel file?

Comment: There is only 1 file in this excel file. The extension is .xlsx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download and unzip file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861323/download-and-unzip-file-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import requests
import zipfile
import io

zip_file_url = "https://www.insee.fr/en/statistiques/series/xlsx/famille/102391902"


r = requests.get(zip_file_url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))


z.extractall()

# Get the list of file names in the zip archive
zip_file_names = z.namelist()

# Check if there is one .xlsx file in the current directory
xlsx_files = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith(".xlsx")]
if len(xlsx_files) == 2:
    for name in xlsx_files:
        if name not in zip_file_names:
            xlsx_file_name = name
    # Overwrite the existing .xlsx file with the file from the zip archive
    if len(zip_file_names) == 1 and zip_file_names[0].endswith(".xlsx"):
        zip_xlsx_file_name = zip_file_names[0]
        os.replace(zip_xlsx_file_name, xlsx_file_name)
        print("File overwritten successfully.")
```

the idea is that you know there is exactly one xlsx file in the current directory, so u can get it's name (with [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith(".xlsx")])

afterwards, you know that there is exactly one xlsx file in your zip archive too, so you know which file to replace by which file

```
if len(xlsx_files) == 2:
```

is useful because the first time you use the script, there will only be one xlsx file in the directory

hope this is clear for you, you may need to adapt this code to your use case

Comment: The current working Directory may not have only one file though. If we always save the file from url A with name A.xlsx, it will automatically overwrite the previous A.xlsx and we can load A.xlsx into pandas since we are sure about the name. This was the idea.

Comment: Well in my first comment I asked "Is there only 1 excel file in the folder in which you want to extract?" to which you replied "There is only 1 file in this excel file. The extension is .xlsx"

Therefore I assumed there was only 1 excel file in the current folder, try to make yourself clearer when asking/answering question

Comment: oops! my bad. I thought you asked about how many files were in the zip file. Anyway, if I extract in a new folder, this can be solved.

Comment: Well it really depends on your needs! but code up top should work if you create a new folder (hopefully)